# Apache Rewrite: Simple exception not working for image types

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This question seems simple to me though I can't seem to get it to work.

I'm trying to do a simple rewrite for all requests except defined image types.

Three very important clarifications:

1. This is being done with the .htaccess file in the image directory that accessed from a browser is located at **example.com/images/** so the .htaccess file is located at public_html/images/.htaccess *locally*.
2. This solution needs to play nicely with the awesome help I received from other people at this question: [Apache Rewrite: image directory based on HTTP host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151876/apache-rewrite-image-directory-based-on-http-host/9154059)
3. I'm using shared hosting, not VPS or dedicated so  my access is limited; I know this isn't going to be complicated anyway.

I've tried the following (along with modifications of it) without success:

**public_html/images/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !\.(gif|jpg|png)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

I think I'm probably just missing something simple here.

Comment: When using the `!` you can't use `$1`. Also $1 only contains 'gif', 'jpg' or 'png', which I don't think you want. You could try using `$0` instead, or `%{REQUEST_URI}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you are trying redirect everything to `index.php` when the request to `images` folder is not a request to an image file.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Your presumption AND code were correct, accepted as answer and up-voted, thanks!